# Why can't I type in input text field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have two input form divs. After clicking register button I want to show the second div where the user can confirm registration. Before the code in RegisterFormInputs function was in the sign-up div and I was able to type in the input fields. Then I moved it into a sepratate function in order to be able to show and hide the div. Now I cannot write anything in the inputs. Why is this happening? How can I solve this?

```
function RegisterForm() {
    const [registerInputValues, setRegisterInputValues] = useState({
        email: '', password: ''
    });

    const [showRegisterForm, setShowRegisterForm] = useState(true);
    const [showRegisterVerificationForm, setShowRegisterVerificationForm] = useState(false);

    const handleRegisterOnChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setRegisterInputValues({ ...registerInputValues, [name]: value });
    };

    const register = () => {
        studentsService.registerStudent(registerInputValues)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
        setShowRegisterForm(false);
        setShowRegisterVerificationForm(true);
    }

    const confirmRegistration = () => {
        studentsService.confirmRegistration(confirmationToken)
        .then(response => {console.log(confirmationToken, response)
        })
        .catch(e => {console.log(e); alert(e.response.data);});
    }

    const RegisterFormInputs = () => {
        return <div>
            <h2 className="loginElement">Create profile</h2>
            <label className="loginElement">
                <span className="loginElement">Email</span>
                <input type="email" name="email" className="loginElement" onChange={handleRegisterOnChange} />
            </label>
            <label className="loginElement">
                <span className="loginElement">Password</span>
                <input type="password" name="password" className="loginElement" onChange={handleRegisterOnChange} />
            </label>
            <button type="button" className="submit" onClick={register}>Register</button>
        </div>
    }

    const RegisterVerificationForm = () => {
        return <div className="verify-registration">
            <h2 className="loginElement text-center">Activate your profile</h2>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Verification token" variant="outlined" onChange={handleTokenOnChange} />
                <Timer initialMinutes={10}/>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-3 text-center">
                <Button variant="contained" onClick={confirmRegistration}>Submit</Button>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="cont mt-5">
                <div className="sub-cont">
                    <div className="form sign-up">
                        {showRegisterForm ? <RegisterFormInputs /> : null}
                        {showRegisterVerificationForm ? <RegisterVerificationForm /> : null}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default RegisterForm;
```

Comment: Are the inputs disabled/readonly ? Use the Inspector if necessary.

Comment: You haven't set the value of the inputs to be the current state. `value={registerInputValues.email}` for example.

Comment: @NiceBooks no, they are not disabled or readonly. I checked that.

Comment: @Sani So you can type something in the inputs ?

Comment: No, I cannot type or copy and paste, but I can use the google autofill option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use useRef() in the handler function and set the state on the register/submit to ref.current. Currently every input change is causing a re-render which is why it's so jumpy.

```
    const formRef = useRef("")
    
    const handleRegisterOnChange = (event) => {
     formRef.current = event;
     //You can see the ref updates when typing, but without a re-render
     console.log(formRef.current);
    };
```

Drilled in to the event.target.value in the input

```
<input
 type="email"
 name="email"
 className="loginElement"
 onChange={(event) => handleRegisterOnChange(event.target.value)}
/>
```

I don't have all of the context for everything but in your register function it may be something like this:

```
 const register = () => {
    studentsService
      .registerStudent(formRef.current)
```

etc.....

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should try to control values of inputs, like this:

```
<input value={registerInputValues.email} type="email" name="email" className="loginElement" onChange={handleRegisterOnChange} />
```

Comment: When I add value={registerInputValues.email}, I can type but char by char. For example, I write one character, then I need to click again to type the second char.

Comment: Sound like focus goes out of input.. But I can't see why. Btw you don't need two states to decide what form to render. Make it look li this, maybe something gonna change: `<div className="form sign-up">{showRegisterForm ? <RegisterFormInputs /> : <RegisterVerificationForm />}
                    </div>`